# Is 300 euros enough for a month in Portugal?

Tags: food-and-drink, lisbon

I am a student with a scholarship to live in Lisbon, Portugal for nine months. The scholarship covers accommodation, health protection, books for the university and the fee for the university. So basically I will need to pay for food and life and transportation and fun.

They give me €300 each month, will that be enough please?

I can't ask my family for money because they can't help. so I will depend on your answer, if it is not enough I will not go.

Comment: To make ends meet, you could consider getting a part time job as a waiter in a restaurant. Perhaps the cook can prepare a free of charge dinner for you using some leftover ingredients that cannot be kept till next day...

Comment: I think a question about the logistics of staying in a particular place for nine months to study is more a matter for [expats.se] than here.

Comment: Depending on the terms of your visa and your scholarship, you might be able to work part-time. If not, there will be little money left over for fun.

Comment: It'll depend on your spending habits. Therefore I'm afraid we can't answer this on tse. Voting to close.

Comment: @CountIblis my visa can't allow me to work

Comment: @o.m. my visa can't allow me to work

Comment: @JoErNanO i do go to concert and love theater, but for this period (9 month) it is okay to just eat and maybe go out in weekend and check some places in portugal.

Comment: @DavidRicherby ok i post the question there, do you know the correct tags please?

Comment: The university accommodation is self-catering? [this NZ study abroad site](http://www.bsec.canterbury.ac.nz/exchange_programme/partners/catolica-lisbon.shtml) for Católica-Lisbon suggests 300 euros/month for expenses other than housing.

Comment: @mkennedy you make my smile again, you make me happy, please how can other people say then it is not enough? i hope you continue with me

Answer (score 1):

Thats a very small budget. Barely enough to cover food and basic needs, but for sure nothing left for fun and extras.

Comment: thanks for unswering, like how much money for one day for eat please?

Comment: If you eat at home and buy it in supermarket, it starts at about 5-7 Euros per day.

Comment: oh my god, that means 3 euro left for one day maximum, so if i pay for transportatoin that means no go out at all. anywan thanks for your time with me

Comment: @SemanotniBarbigano Where will you go every day? You will live at the university. You don't need transport during the week. Maybe at weekends. And of course you're meant to be studying; this will take much of your time. Unless you plan to go get drunk every weekend, I think you will be fine.

Comment: @MichaelHampton i checked the metro, the university residence needs 3 metro stations to go to the university, the ticket is 1.8 euro, so two tickets is 3.6 euro per day, but there is a monthly card for metro for 34 euro in lisbon. please can you tell me now if 256 enough ?

Comment: Three metro stops, in many cities that is walking distance. Take a good backpack and learn to like the walk. Also makes you do not need to exersize as much.

Answer (score 1):

13 May to 19 June 2015 in northern Spain, I had lodging and many of my meals provided.  But I spent about €270, most of it in restaurants and snacks.  Take a look at numbeo.com or expatistan.com for cost estimates for the city you're thinking of.  Numbeo used to have a customization feature where you put in details about your lifestyle and get an estimate to fit those.  Sadly, they removed that feature.